# Splitting an html string into the seperate div tags

Tags: html, vb.net, string

I have a string full of html & which reads

```
Dim strHml as string = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><div class="normal">Dog</div>
<div class="normal">Cat</div><div class="normal">Elephant</div><div class="normal">Giraffe</div><div class="normal"><div><p>Random Div</p></div>Lion</div><div>Wolf</div>
<div>Tiger</div></body></html>"
```

I want to somehow be able to pull all the div tags  and their content 
and put each one into an array
have looked at split function and regular expressions but no clear and easy solution has presented itself as yet.

I have amended this slightly to incorporate nested div tags, but those tags I still need returning in the format :-

```
<div class="normal"><div><p>Random Div</p></div>Lion</div>
```

Comment: Yeah what I presented is a bit of 'Dumbed down' version of what I am trying to achieve, but the following comments have been very helpful. I amended the regex slightly as some of the divs I have in the actual application have classes applied to them.
So I changed it to Dim reg = New Regex("<div .*>(.*?)</div>")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this in vb.net using regex.

Is that what you needed?

```
Dim reg = New Regex("<div>(.*?)</div>")

        Dim matches = reg.Matches(strHml)

        For Each mat As Match In matches
            Dim s As String
            s = mat.Value
        Next mat
```

Comment: That will work if: there are no nested div's and the div('s) do not span multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, i aggree, what th OP needs to specify is what they want in the case of nested divs, and can remove the multi line by removing tabs and end lines. Other than that i would try a html parser
http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vb_internet/html/article.php/c4815
http://www.netomatix.com/products/Documentmanagement/HtmlParserNet.aspx